# Python AttributeError in Testing Goat

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium

I've just started working through [Test-Driven Development with Python](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/) and don't understand the AttributeError I'm getting as it's different from the one in the book.

The code to run a selenium test is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest

class new_visitor_test(unittest.TestCase):

        def set_up(self):
                self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

        def tear_down(self):
                self.browser.quit()

        def test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later(self):
                self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')

                self.assertIn('To-Do', self.browser.title)
                self.fail('Finish the test!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main(warnings='ignore')
```

and the error should be:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "functional_tests.py", line 18, in
test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later
self.assertIn('To-Do', self.browser.title)
AssertionError: 'To-Do' not found in 'Welcome to Django'
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functional_tests.py", line 13, in test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later
    self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
AttributeError: 'new_visitor_test' object has no attribute 'browser'
```

What's causing this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setup method should be called [`setUp()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp), the tear down method - [`tearDown()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown):

```
class new_visitor_test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later(self):
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')

        self.assertIn('To-Do', self.browser.title)
        self.fail('Finish the test!')
```

The methods are actually [named correctly in the book](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch02.html#_the_python_standard_library_8217_s_unittest_module).

Comment: oh, ok, so that must be specific to `unittest` rather than a style choice.  I knew this would come down to some kind of newbie typing error! Thanks!

Comment: yeah, I'm embarrassed!